# Opensource .Net Jabber/XMPP server?

Tags: c#, .net, xmpp

I've seen quite a few examples of XMPP clients in .Net, and I've seen quite a few servers in various languages, but I'm looking for a .Net version (opensource if possible) of a XMPP server. It doesn't particularly have to be stable, or full of features, I just want something that works a little. Reliability is not really an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some that I found:

- http://code.google.com/p/goodwarejabber/downloads/list (a bit old...)

EDIT: Note the comment below by the author of jabber-net, noting that jabber-net is **not** for writing servers:

- http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/wiki/FAQ_License

As an alternative, take a look at this SO question:

- [Jabber-net integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150700/jabber-net-integration)

or at these libraries:

- http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/

that would allow you to create your own (if that is an option for you).

Comment: (speaking as author of Jabber-Net)  As the license on Jabber-Net says, please don't use it to write servers.  Writing server components is just fine, which may be what you actually want.

Comment: @Joe Thanks, edited to note the licensing terms!

Answer (score 1):

You can download and take a look at trial version of MatriX library. It contains a sample on how to implement your own server.

http://www.ag-software.de/matrix-xmpp-sdk/download/

Download the MatriX for .NET version.

You could ask the support forum for help actually

http://forum.ag-software.de/

Answer (score 0):

Coversant solution : [SOAPBOX Server](http://www.coversant.com/products/soapbox-server)